# Form не является допустимым идентификатором

Tags: asp.net

Я переделываю html страницу в MasterPage. Все работает за исключением одного. У меня есть форма для ввода и кнопка, так к ним css-стили не применились. У меня в MasterPage после тега body идет уже один `<form id="form1" runat="server">` в который входит все div-ы включая форму для ввода с кнопкой. Так вот я незнаю, как сделать так чтобы стили применились и к форме. Писал `<form id="search-form" runat="server">` но в таком случае выходит ошибка: "form id не является допустимым идентификатором".

```
 // Кусок html кода кнопки с формой для ввода вставленный в MasterPage
<form id="search-form" class="search-form clearfix" method="get" action="#">
    <input class="search-term required" type="text" id="s" name="s" 
         placeholder="Введите ключевые слова для поиска" 
         title="* Please enter a search term!" />
    <input class="search-btn" type="submit" value="Search" />
    <div id="search-error-container"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: видимо из-за минуса в `id`. (`search-form`) Сделайте к примеру `searchform` или `search_form`

Answer (score 3):

В asp.net допускается только один серверный элемент Form (runat="server"). Поскольку в мастер-пейдж уже определена серверная форма, то на использующих мастер-пейдж страницах, их больше не должно быть.